# Cannot retrieve password AND username

Tags: php

alright, I thought this code was working today (Specifically the setSession function) however, i've come to realize that its only selecting the username not the password and allowing the user to log in. You can put anything you want into the form (

```
<?php
class user
{
    protected $db;
    protected $uid;
    protected $email;
    protected $username;
    protected $citcode;
    protected $password;
    public $error;
    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    function error($error)
    {
        $this->error = $error;  
    }
    function passwordCrypt($password)
    {
        $password = crypt($password, '$2a$07$ThisIsSparta$');
        return $password;
    }
    function registerUser($username, $password, $email, $citcode, $db)
    {
        $verifyCC = $this->checkCitCode($citcode);
        $verifyUser = $this->checkUsername($username, $email);
        if($verifyUser == true)
        {
            if($verifyCC == true)
            {
                $password = $this->passwordCrypt($password);
                $username = $this->db->real_escape_string($username);
                $email = $this->db->real_escape_string($email);
                $date = date('Y-m-d');
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, joindate) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}', NOW());";
                $sql .= "INSERT INTO bank_accounts(type, balance) VALUES ('personal', '10000');";
                $query = $this->db->multi_query($sql);
                if(!$query)
                {
                    $this->error('Could not register user, please try again later.');
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->error('Could not Verify Citizen Code');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->error('Username/Password is already taken');
        }
    }
    function checkCitCode($citcode)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT amount, active FROM citizen_codes WHERE citizen_code = '{$citcode}';";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if(!$query)
        {
            die(mysqli_error($this->db));
        }
        else
        {
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
            {
                if($row['active'] >= $row['amount'])
                {
                    return false;   
                }
                else
                {
                    $active = $row['active'] +1;
                    $sql = "UPDATE citizen_codes SET active = '{$active}' WHERE citizen_code = '{$citcode}';";
                    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                    if(!$query)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function checkUsername($username, $email)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' OR email = '{$email}'";
        $que = $this->db->query($sql);
        if(!$que)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $row = $que->fetch_array();
            if($row[0] > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;    
            }
        }   
    }
    function setSession($username, $password)
    {
        $password = $this->passwordCrypt($password);
        $username = $this->db->real_escape_string($username);
        $sql = "SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}';";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if(!$query)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            while($row = $query->fetch_array())
            {
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row[0];
            }
        }
}
    }
```

And for reference, he's the login script.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    if(!isset($_GET['mode']))
    {
    $user = new user($db);
    ?>
<style type='text/css'>
table { background-color: #666; padding: 1%; width: 20%; margin: 0 auto; }
table th { background-color:#ccc; }
table td { padding: 3%; background-color: #f1f1f1; font-weight: bold;} 
</style>
<form method='post' action='login.php?mode=set'>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th colspan='3'><h3>Citizen Login</h3></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Username</td><td>:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' id='username'></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type='password' name='password' id='password'></td>
</tr>
<tr><th colspan='3'><input type='submit' /></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan='3'><span style='font-size: 12px;'>Don't have an account? <a href='register.php'>Register Today!</a><br /> Forgotten Password/Username?</th>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/constants.php');
    $user = new user($db);
    $user->setSession($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    echo $user->error;
    }
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question for us? Also, can you try to trim the code to the bare minimum needed to explain the problem?

Comment: "Here's all of my code, please fix it" questions aren't really the kind of questions that SO was intended for.  Answers to this question are not very likely to help future visitors.

Comment: I asked my question, apparently not clearly. Why isn't the password being selected? That's all I want to know. because the password encryption works, the password is being passed to SQL (as far as i know at least, i'm not getting any errors) and the SQL can select the Username, however it will not select the password.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. The password field length in the DB wasn't long enough.